# assignment of String at CSR10 chip (uEnerfy)

Tags: c

i have a simple program that compile in c at visual,
but not compile at CSR10 id and I don't know how to do it simple:
it say error: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type;

```
char *globalString;
int test(void);

void test()
{
    globalString    = "ABCD";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

global string (char *) will point to a constant (const char *) "ABCD". So, you discard the "const" qualifier. Since GlobalString isn't a constant, it will warn you about that.